# android filling array with strings from string.xml

Tags: android

what I have learned so far:

in strings.xml I have bunch of

```
<string name="q1">what is the name of blah blah</string>
<string name="q2">what is the name of blah blah</string>
<string name="q3">what is the name of blah blah</string>
<string name="q4">what is the name of blah blah</string>
```

and in the main class i have to create an array of question objects to access them
throughout the main class like

```
 private Question[] mQuestionList = new Question[]{
  new Question(R.string.q1, true),
  new Question(R.string.q2, false),
  new Question(R.string.q3, true),
  new ...
 }
```

What im curious about is that if I have 200 questions, i know i have to write each of them out in stirng.xml file, however i think 200 "new Question(R.string.qx, true/false)" statements in the main class is not the right way. i believe that there is some way of filling the mQuestionList array in much easier way. If there is what is it?

Answer (score 4):

You can put this in values/arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="array_name">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
</string-array>
```

then do

```
String[] questionStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.arrays.array_name);
mQuestionList = new Question[questionStrings.length];

for (int i = 0; i < questionStrings.length; i++) {
    mQuestionList[i] = new Question( questionStrings[i], ...
```

If the second parameter, the boolean one, is different for each question, store them an a new array in values/arrays.xml